# Cloundfront gets locked on index.html

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have the following distribution.
https://dhzcuvpl3uus.cloudfront.net

for the sake of similicity, i have 2 objects:

- index.html
- manifest.json

When I am accessing for the first time (after hard cache or icognito mode) the `manifest.json` ([https://dhzcuvpl3uus.cloudfront.net/manifest.json](https://dhzcuvpl3uus.cloudfront.net)) object, i can see the content.

However, after accessing the `index.html` object, i lose access to `manifest` json. It shows the index.html even when i am requesting the `manifest.json` object by the url.

It can be fixed with hard cache.

what is the reason with this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that your manifest is working.

At your manifest you have

```
"start_url": "./index.html"
```

And in your index.html you have:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

So once index.html is called your browser caches that your "Web Application" start URL is ./index.html ...

Even if you try to access -> https://dhzcuvpl3uus.cloudfront.net/shazam
it will call what the browser has on cache from the manifest.json

```
./index.html
```

Tl dr: Your manifest is working, and your browser is caching.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have changed `"start_url": "./index.html` value to `"start_url": "."` but it doesn't work. also are you sure this applies to desktop browser? i thought it applies only to PWA insalled app. any further suggestions?

Comment: Yes. It does apply to desktop Browsers for compatibility. The best testing is to use curl (text browser) that does not cache the requests.
curl -l -v https://dhzcuvpl3uus.cloudfront.net/manifest.json  OR
curl -l -v https://dhzcuvpl3uus.cloudfront.net/manifest.json   
  
You will see the "raw" content.